# Can an interface extend the Serializable interface?

Tags: java, serialization

Is it possible to create an interface extending the Serializable interface?

If yes, will that extended interface behave like the Serilizable interface? If not, why?

Comment: What happens if you try?

Comment: after the first time you get `ComputerWillExplodeException`, you stop experimenting with things.

Comment: i could have tried, wanted to make sure can we do that. so now i got the answer

Comment: Why don't you just use another interface, without inheritance? Inheriting will obfuscate the initial goal of the marker interface (declaring the intention) IMO.

Comment: it would have taken 2 minutes to try it, and it took already 6 to verify.

Comment: And now you need to post a new questions 'what are the implications of class being serializable', 'when is it a bad idea to make class a serializable' and 'how to design a serializable class'.

Read the chapter about serialization from Josh Bloch's Effective Java.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, you can extend the `Serializable` interface.  If you do, all classes that implement the new subinterface will also be implementing `Serializable`.

Answer (score 8):

> So can we do that?

Yes

> will that extended interface will take
>   the same effect as the Serilizable
>   interface?

Yes

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's normal. I did it once when decided that all classes in my domain should be serializable. They implemented some interface already so I simply extended that interface from Serializable (as you describe).

Answer (score 1):

I am explaining this by a situation often encountered in android. If you want to pass the instance of a custom listener(interface), to fragment, then the listener(interface) extend the Serializable can be a option for you. eg

Suppose there is an Interface :

```
public interface OnDurationChangeListener extends Serializable {
    public void onDurationChange(Duration duration);
}
```

from an Activity I want to Export the instance Listener(interface) to Fragment.

```
bundle.putSerializable(ARGUMENT_LISTENER, new OnDurationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDurationChange(Duration duration) {
        // some code   
    }
});
```

And in fragment you can Get this Listener instance as:

```
mListener = (OnDaysSelectListener) getArguments().getSerializable(ARGUMENT_LISTENER);
```

And from the fragment I can Call the Callback method in activity as

```
mListener.onDaysSelect(mWeeKDayList);
```

Comment: I have tried something similar and it crash saying my `activity` it's not `serializable`.

Comment: Instances of `Activity` cannot implement the `Serializable` interface because it extends `Context`.